# Running a function on a remote server via SSH in a script

Tags: function, shell, ssh

I Have shell script with few functions. I need to run this on 2 different machines for `n` number of times. Can I call the function as mentioned below and execute it? Or is there any other way to do it?

```
#!/usr/bash

execCommand () {
  #few statements here
}

getStatus() {
  #few statements here
}

main () {
  execCommand
  getStatus
}

$machine1="machine1"
$machine2="machine2"
$user="username"
$n=2

while [$n -le 2]
 do
   ssh $user@$machine1 'main'
   sleep 100
    ssh $user@$machine2 'main'
    n=$n+1
 done
```

Comment: The remote machine will not know the function `main`. You have to send everything through the `ssh` connection. You can also copy the files to the remote machine and then ssh to execute it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script: Run function from script over ssh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107610/shell-script-run-function-from-script-over-ssh)

Answer (score 3):

There's no straightforward way to do that. But you can extract all the function definitions and inject them as a command at the beginning of your remote command:

```
ssh "$user@$machine1" "$(declare -f); main"
```

Notice that you still might have problems with global variables and other resources.

Comment: You can also pass a single function definition with $(declare -f funcname)