# executing method on remote machine with sshpass shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

How to execute a method on remote machine connecting with sshpass
Following is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkfunctioncall() {
cd "/home/user"
mkdir "remotecalltest"

}

sshpass -p "$serverpwd" ssh "$serveruser"@"$serverip" checkfunctioncall
```

but I am getting below error:

> bash: checkfunctioncall: command not found

Please suggest

I am specifically looking for solution with sshpass, as I need to login to remote server with a password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script: Run function from script over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107610/shell-script-run-function-from-script-over-ssh)

Comment: @Andrew: No, Its not, I already saw this post, but  I am specifically looking for solution with sshpass, as I need to login to remote server with a password

Comment: You just can't execute locally defined function, because the remote machine knows nothing about it. Write the script you want to run, copy it to the remote machine and then run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will remove the above error.

```
sshpass -p "$serverpwd" ssh "$serveruser"@"$serverip" << EOSSH
checkfunctioncall(){
cd "/home/user"
mkdir "remotecalltest"
}
checkfunctioncall
EOSSH
```

Comment: what if I want to call another function from this function (which also needs to be executed on remote server); it again gives same error

Comment: Set the correct PATH variable in your script function OR set it as on the command itself.

Comment: @vtha for me it worked.without giving the PATH variable.