# How to run functions and local resources over SSH in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have a shell script file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONF_FILE="/tmp/settings.conf" #settings.conf contains OS_NAME="Caine Linux"
source $CONF_FILE

display_os_name() { echo "My OS is:" $OS_NAME }

#using the function locally works fine
display_os_name
#displays: My OS is: Caine Linux

#using the function on the remote host doesn't work
ssh user@host "$(declare -f); display_os_name"
#displays: My OS is:
```

If I remove the  `-f` and I use just `ssh user@host "$(declare); display_os_name"` it works but displays these errors and warnings:

```
bash: line 10: BASHOPTS: readonly variable
bash: line 18: BASH_VERSINFO: readonly variable
bash: line 26: EUID: readonly variable
bash: line 55: PPID: readonly variable
bash: line 70: SHELLOPTS: readonly variable
bash: line 76: UID: readonly variable
```

If I use `ssh user@host "$(declare); display_os_name >/dev/null"` to suppress the warnings only the output of the function is suppressed (My OS is: Caine Linux), not the warnings.

Is there a way to run local functions together with sourced local files on a remote SSH host?

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107610/shell-script-run-function-from-script-over-ssh#22107893) helps you ?

Comment: @krampstudio, no it doesn't. If I use `typeset -f` only the function is available on the remote host, not the imported settings file.

Comment: Ultimately, everything you want to use on the remote host has to be *sent* to the remote host. `ssh` is just a connection tool, not a distributed computing framework.

Comment: `2>/dev/null` instead of `>/dev/null` to suppress the error messages rather than the standard output. Of course, it'd be better to fix the source of those error messages.

Comment: Since you're `source`ing the file, you could just put its contents into the string sent to the remote host for execution. `ssh user@host "$(</tmp/settings.conf); $(declare -f); display_os_name"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy approach (if your local side is Linux) is to use `set -a` to enable automatic export before your `source` command; copy `/proc/self/environ` on stdin; and parse it into a set of variables on the remote side.

Because `BASHOPTS`, `EUID`, etc. aren't environment variables, this avoids trying to modify them. (If you were complying with [POSIX recommendations](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) and using lowercase names for your own variables, you could even go as far as to ignore all-caps variables entirely).

```
set -a # enable export of all variables defined, **before** the source operation
source /tmp/settings.conf

import_env() {
  while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
    printf -v "${item%%=*}" "%s" "${item#*=}" && export "$item"
  done
}

cat /proc/self/environ | ssh user@host "$(declare -f); import_env; display_os_name"
```

Even easier is to just copy the file you want to source over the wire.

```
ssh user@host "$(declare -f); $(</tmp/settings.conf); display_os_name"
```

Comment: Thanks Charles, I tried the file copying for now and it works. The script is small for now so I can change my variables to lower-case, but how will that be helpful? How can I "ignore all-caps variables entirely"? Thank you!

Comment: Inside your `while` loop (before the `printf`), `[[ $item =~ ^[[:upper:]]*= ]] && continue` is one way to skip any variable with an all-uppercase name, and thus ensure that you're only transmitting variables inside the namespace POSIX reserves for application use. The advantage here is that anything like `LD_PRELOAD`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `LC_LOCALE`, etc that isn't part of your script but is local system-level configuration gets ignored; likewise, keeps you safe even if someone *does* flag a shell variable (`BASHOPTS`, etc) for export.

Answer (score 0):

This method works using GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

```
#!/bin/bash
#################################################################################

source $CONF_FILE

#settings.conf contains OS_NAME="Caine Linux"
CONF_FILE="/tmp/settings.conf"
special_file='!abc123'
OS_NAME='my_server'
    
display_os_name() 
{
    echo "My OS is:" $OS_NAME
}

ssh -tt -q user@host << EOT
    
    CONF_FILE=$CONF_FILE
    special_file=$\\special_file
    OS_NAME=$OS_NAME
    $(typset -f display_os_name)
    display_os_name

EOT
#################################################################################
```