ssh into remote servers, get systeminfo and print out in local terminal
I have the following script and when I run it, I don't get the expected output to the local terminal.
I am assuming it must be the variables that I am assigning in the heredoc that is not getting printed as I expect.
#!/bin/bash
#
for host in `cat hosts.txt`
do
  ssh $host << EOF
IP=`ip a |grep inet|grep ens192 | awk '{print $2}'`
CPU=`cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep "physical id" | wc -l`
MEM=`getconf -a | grep PAGESIZE | awk '{print $2}'`
DISK=`lsblk |grep disk | awk '{print $4}'`
EOF
done 
printf "ip_address      cpu     memory  disk\n"
echo "----------        ---     ------  ----"
printf "$IP     $CPU    $MEM    $DISK"

I am not sure how to fix the issue.  Also I hope that if hosts.txt contains 5 hosts, it would print 5 lines.
Thank you in advanced.

<<'EOF' to stop the expansions in your code from being run locally before ssh runs. Or, better, use the declare -f method to serialize a function to run remotely, as other Q&A on our site demonstrates.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50528892/how-to-run-functions-and-local-resources-over-ssh-in-a-shell-script f/e demonstrates the technique at hand.

...in the linked duplicate, the answer by mkelement0 is IMHO the best currently available; but personally I'd use the declare -f technique from the link in the prior comment instead.

BTW, for host in $(cat hosts.txt) or its backtick-based legacy-syntax equivalent is bad form -- see DontReadLinesWithFor.
