# How to excute command in remote server which include backticks, awk and assign value to variable?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to execute following line in remote server

`` export EXTERNAL_IP=`hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'` && echo $EXTERNAL_IP ``

which fill EXTERNAL_IP on the remote host.

How should I write this line using `ssh MyServer MyCommand` ?

Comment: `ssh MyServer "hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'"`?

Comment: @Cyrus point is to fill EXTERNAL_IP

Comment: @MortezaMalekabadi just use: ssh myserver "export EXTERNAL_IP=`hostname -I | awk '{print $1}' && echo Its: $EXTERNAL_IP"` if you want to use EXTERNAL_IP

Comment: The syntax for executing commands via ssh, is `ssh yourserver commands`. Where the commands (if you want to execute two or more) must be with " " or ' ' (there are differences between using single quotes and double quotes

Comment: You can consider using `\$` when you do `echo $EXTERNAL_IP`, for example `echo \$EXTERNAL_IP`. That because may exist a variable called EXTERNAL_IP in your current shell session or, unless in zsh, without `\$` will not show anything when run the ssh commands.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by temporarily setting a variable on a remote machine?

Comment: @MortezaMalekabadi, environment variables only live as long as the processes they're set in do. The moment `ssh` exits the variable is gone, so what's the point?

Comment: Mind, for backticks &c., the common practice is just to write a shell function and tell your shell to expand it into the ssh command line; that way all the escaping is done for you automatically. The process is described in [Shell script: Run function from script over ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107610), and if you don't have any problem _not_ solved by following that practice, I'd be tempted to mark this question as a duplicate. (It's not obvious, but that's the point of keeping duplicates in our knowledgebase, to act as signposts)

Comment: ```myfunc() { export EXTERNAL_IP=`hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'` && echo $EXTERNAL_IP; }; ssh MyServer "$(declare -f myfunc); myfunc"```

Comment: ...mind, you shouldn't be using backticks in modern shell scripts at all. `$( ... )` is the modern replacement, standardized by the publication of POSIX.2 in the early 1990s. It's not just more visually obvious, it also reduces bugs because it doesn't change how backticks and backslashes are parsed inside command substitutions; nesting backticks is a royal pain.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you so mcuh,  myfunc() { export EXTERNAL_IP=`hostname -I | awk '{print $1}'` && echo $EXTERNAL_IP; }; ssh MyServer "$(declare -f myfunc); myfunc" works perfectly. I would be grateful if you could post this as an answer.

Comment: @EdMorton I want to do some automation with gitlab-ci I need to fill varibale to use them in docker compose.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon Thanks Edgar that was really good insight