# Run a ssh -> rsync-command from bash script and wait until rsync ended

Tags: bash, debian

I need a little help with my bash script, where I want to ssh on a remote server and execute a script with multiple rsync commands.

My current script looks like this (after some pre-check for day and time, but this is working:

```
logger -p local0.info -t dhcp-join-notify "NAS is reachable, start syncing"
sleep 1
ssh admin@192.168.99.8 -p 2222 "bash -s" < /root/qnap-ssh.sh
sleep 1
logger -p local0.info -t dhcp-join-notify "Send poweroff to server"
sleep 1
ssh admin@192.168.99.8 -p 2222 'poweroff'
sleep 1
```

Additional I've the file /root/qnap-ssh.sh with content like this

```
#!/bin/bash
/share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Entware-ng/bin/rsync -Pvarzz rsync://192.168.99.6/qnap-public2/Digital-Fotos /share/HDA_DATA/Public &&
/share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Entware-ng/bin/rsync -Pvarzz rsync://192.168.99.6/qnap-public2/eBooks /share/HDA_DATA/Public &&
/share/HDA_DATA/.qpkg/Entware-ng/bin/rsync -Pvarzz rsync://192.168.99.6/docker-data /share/HDA_DATA/Public/docker-data
```

When the script is running I see via syslog, that the commands run through, but the important part with "ssh admin@192.168.99.8 -p 2222 "bash -s" < /root/qnap-ssh.sh" is only visible for 1-2 seconds.
How do I let the script wait until this part has been finished?

Thanks for help, Dominik

Comment: You are feeding the whole qnap-ssh.sh at onec to ssh, so ssh sends it to bash as quickly as possible. How about processing the input line by line? Another possibility would be to copy the script to the remote host, and run it there.

Comment: Thanks for the first hint :-)
What do you mean with processing the input line by line?
Executing every ssh-rsync command from my first script?

I'd like to keep the script on my server to modify it, if necessary

Comment: I meant to run one ssh command for each input line. Of course this is less efficient than your approach, but an alternative, if transfering the script to the remote host is not an option.

Comment: Other possibilities which come to my mind, would be to define the code to be executed, inside a function, and transfer the function to the remote host. This is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107610/shell-script-run-function-from-script-over-ssh). Yet another possibility is to start `ssh` from an [_expect_ script](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/expect-script-ssh-example-tutorial).